# regex not giving all the possible matches

Tags: c#, regex, overlapping-matches

I need to get all the possible matches for a given regular expression and word in c#. But the Regex.Matches() function is not giving it. For eg.

```
Regex.Matches("datamatics","[^aeiou]a[^aeiou]")
```

returns only two matches which are

```
dat
mat
```

it is not giving "tam" as a match. Can somebody explain to me why it is not giving "tam" as a match and how can I get all the three?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't get overlapping matches in Regex. You have several ways to work around it, though. You can either use `Regex.Match`, and specify a starting index (use a loop to go through your whole string), or you can use lookbehinds or lookaheads, like so:

```
  (?=[^aeiou]a)[^aeiou]
```

This works because lookbehinds and lookaheads do not consume the characters. It returns a `Match` which contains the index of the match. You'd need to use that instead of captures, since only one character is captured.

Answer (score 1):

Use this regex

```
(?<=([^aeiou]))a(?=([^aeiou]))
```

.net supports group capture in lookarounds..cheers

Your code would be

```
var lst= Regex.Matches(input,regex)
              .Cast<Match>()
              .Select(x=>x.Groups[1].Value+"a"+x.Groups[2].Value)
              .ToList();
```

Now you can iterate over lst

```
foreach(String s in lst)
{
     s;//required strings
}
```

Comment: @dasblinkenlight they are supported in .net..:P

Comment: Ah, I didn't see your little trick - you added capturing groups around non-capturing lookaheads and lookbehinds! That's tricky, but I guess whatever works, works.